# Options I've passed to JVM seems to have no effect

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I am working with an application that uses bean shell scripting to pass java (jvm) arguments. My application needs more than the default 88M PermGen. I've tried all manner of methods from specifying the arguments seperately, to all together, to all by their lonesome. In particular I am trying to load the JVM with `-XX:PermGen=128M` and `-XX:MaxPermGen=256M`. No mater what I have tried these arguments don't seem to be having any effect (I am using VisualVM to monitor resource usage).

My last resort, I think, is to configure the JVM for the machine to default to 256M perm gen but I can't find anything online that says how (or IF) you can do this without passing in the option as flags.

Anyone know if I am barking up the wrong tree? If I am not, can you tell me how I can change the defaults? (JDK6)

Comment: What's your platform?

Comment: Are you sure you won't missed M letter in `-XX:MaxPermGen=256` (which says to set size in 256 **M**egabytes)?

Comment: Typo on my side. I am specifying an M at the end to designate the size as megabytes.

Comment: Platform is Windows 7 with jdk 6 u34

Comment: Could you add the code which launches JVM?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to it. I suspect that perhaps the process that receives my parameters, which in turn triggers the application to start, is not able to support all JVM args. That is why my question was whether or not it is possible to set DEFAULT JVM values for memory consumption. What I mean by that is altering the 32M default PermGen value that gets allocated when you type java "..." so that it allocates 256M by default.

Comment: I've managed to solve it. Turns out that the configuration, despite being documented as the way to do it, is never passed. I modified another script file that appears to actually start the program running and the memory settings were honoured.

Comment: @jardineworks go ahead and post that as an answer to your own question then, and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at [Hotspot JVM options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html), it's possible to see that there are no options `-XX:PermGen` or `-XX:MaxPermGen`, but there is`-XX:MaxPermSize` which is 64m by default.

So you just simply need to use correct name of option:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```